# File.Exists returns false when file exists

Tags: c#

```
        try
        {
            string directory = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents";
            string filename = "DBCS.config";
            string path = Path.Combine(directory, filename);

            if (File.Exists(filename))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("I exist");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
```

The code skips the messagebox everytime.

I checked to see if the file is actually there. The file is a simple text file.

Comment: Your path isnt pointing to the directory. Use a directory object and pass that into file.Exists.

Comment: Why the downvote?  Seems to be a reasonable question to me.

Comment: So you really think  there is a bug in File.Exists?

Comment: Thanks. It was a bug in my program (obviously). I didn't see it. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the variable `path` instead of `filename`

```
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    MessageBox.Show("I exist");
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You want this:

```
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    MessageBox.Show("I exist");
}
```

You have mistakenly used the filename instead of the full path for `Exists`.